# Glade GTK3 Python treeview toggles wont toggle

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

I have an application where the GtkCellRendererToggle does not trigger a callback when I use Glade to build the the application. Specifically, if the toggle button is set to True when I click on it, the callback is executed, but when the button is toggled to False, the callback is not triggered.

I am using Python 3, GTK3 and Glade 3.22.1 I am including the Python source code along with the associated xml. The working example comes from the python gtk3 tutorial: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cellrenderers.html

> Blockquote

```
<object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview">
      <property name="visible">True</property>
      <property name="can_focus">True</property>
      <property name="model">liststore</property>
      <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection">
              <property name="mode">none</property>
          </object>
      </child>
      <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="togglecolumn">
          <property name="title">Togggle</property>
      <child>
          <object class="GtkCellRendererToggle" id="togglerenderer">
              <signal name="toggled" handler="on_cell_toggled" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
              <attributes>
                  <attribute name="activatable">0</attribute>
                  <attribute name="active">0</attribute>
              </attributes>
      </child>
</object>
```

/>

> Blockquote

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("example.glade")
window = builder.get_object("window")
# Load list data.
self.liststore = builder.get_object ("liststore")

builder.connect_signals(self)
window.show()

def on_cell_toggled(self, widget, path):
    self.liststore[path][0] = not self.liststore[path][0]
```

/>

What you will see is 3 rows of toggle buttons with the first and third checked. If you click on one of the checked boxes, the on_cell_toggle callback is executed, but once it has been toggled to false, it no longer triggers the callback. In the example in the tutorial the toggle works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the activatable property to the same column as active property:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute name="activatable">0</attribute>
     <attribute name="active">0</attribute>
</attributes>
```

should be:

```
<attributes>
     <attribute name="active">0</attribute>
</attributes>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the toggles. There is a problem with the radio buttons, but I have more testing to do. My main application uses only a single toggle button.

Comment: Then accept it as correct so other people coming here know it worked. It's the check mark at the left of my answer.